# put the value of radio button and checkbox into 1 row in database via php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, phpmyadmin, radio-button

how to insert the value of radio button and checkbox together into 1 row database..for example the table contains name of menu and the size of the food. The Database table contains food and price..so when we choose which menu we want with checkbox, the value of checkbox will store in food(database's table) and choose the size of our food use radio button, the value of radiobutton will store in price(database's table)

please help me
I'm a newbie in this field
thanks

here is the code

menu.php

```
<form action="price.php" method="post">

Menu : <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Siomay" name="tile[]">Siomay <br>
<input type="radio" name="field" value="4" />Small
<input type="radio" name="fiel" value="5" />Large<br>


<input name="confirm" type=submit id="confirm" value='Confirm'>

</form>
```

price.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("project1", $con);

$insert="INSERT INTO menu(name, price) VALUES ('".$_POST['tile']"','".$_POST['field']"')";

if (!mysql_query($insert, $con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con) 
?>
```

Comment: please make some code explanation so it will easy to understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally use the insert function from mysql. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) is some basic but good explanation and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) you can find the official one with much more details, but also more difficult to understand for newbies. But you have to use it from PHP as you can see in the first link examples.

The values are received as regular [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) when read from php. REMEMBER to also use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

With more info (read the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)) about your project, table names, code etc we'd be able to help you more. Use returns to separate the ideas, what you wrote is really difficult to read. Also, it'd would be great if you included [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far, so you don't give the feeling that you want us to do your work.

EDIT

I thought that you were much more of a newbie until you put your code so I posted some really basic examples. Now here's some code that might work:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("project1", $con);

$Tile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[tile]);
$Field = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[field]);

if ( !empty($Tile) && !empty($Field) )
{
  $insert="INSERT INTO menu(name, price) VALUES ('$Tile','$Field')";
  if (!mysql_query($insert, $con))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
echo "1 record added";
}
else echo "Please select at least 1 menu.";

mysql_close($con) 
?>
```

Why is the name `tile[]` in menu.php? Tested with only `tile`? I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm only saying I never saw it. Also, what problems do you have? It doesn't save anything?

Note that `if ( !empty($Tile) && !empty($Field) )` is also used to prevent users trying to do malicious things to your page, not only to make sure they chosed one menu.

Comment: the code is working well...
tile[] is just the tested name :)
the problem is when I choose the option of checkbox and choose the option of radio button, the value of checkbox and radio button didn't recorded in the same row...

anw, now I have 3 menu choices..each menu have 2 size options which is radio button..that's mean for each size option there should have different name right...the name I mean is field[]

Comment: By the same row did you mean the same cell? Because it's completely different. The code I posted SHOULD put them in the same row. If not, then it's a completely different kind of problem, because the code is right. Maybe some really weird configuration problem. Haven't seen anything like that ever thought.